# How to model relationship with two different foreign keys in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following:

```
public class Arm
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // Works fine without the Robot reference 
    public Robot Robot { get; set; }
}

public class Robot
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Arm LeftArm { get; set; }
    public Arm RightArm { get; set; }
}
```

I'm imagining tables like:

```
create table Arms (
  Id int identity primary key
);

create table Robots (
  Id int identity,
  LeftArmId int references Arms,
  RightArmId int references Arms,
)
```

How do I configure EF Core to do it this way?

Answer (score 0):

The two typical approaches would be to use FK properties or FK shadow properties on your Robot entity to point at the respective arm. When you remove the "Robot" reference from the Arm, EF is doing this behind the scenes automatically, assuming there is a many-to-one association-based relationship:

```
public class Robot
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(LeftArm))]
    public int LeftArmId { get; set; }
    public Arm LeftArm { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(RightArm))]
    public int RightArmId { get; set; }
    public Arm RightArm { get; set; }
}
```

... or with shadow properties (properties EF manages behind the scenes but not exposed for tampering in the entity)

```
public class Robot
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LeftArmId")]
    public Arm LeftArm { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RightArmId")]
    public Arm RightArm { get; set; }
}
```

In EF's convention case with code-first where it can modify your schema, the FK names would be something like "Arm_Id" and "Arm_Id1".

Now one consideration with the relationship to consider would be whether the relationship is an association (many-to-one) or ownership. The association model would be something like having several arms like "Claw", "Scoop", "Hook", "Winch". Where as you create a robot, you associate a left and/or right "arm" reference to each of these arm rows. Many robots reference a "Claw" arm, either left of right (or both) The caveat here is that Robots reference an arm rather than own it. For any specific arm we wouldn't have a single Robot to go back to, it could be many robots.

However, if the relationship is more of an ownership arrangement where a robot has 2 specific arms that are shared with no other robot, then you will need to be explicit with the relationship, both for EF and for data integrity.

The first change would be on the Arm entity/table itself. An Arm is going to belong to a Robot so it's unique Key should include the RobotId:

```
public class Arm
{
    public int RobotId { get; set; }
    public int ArmNumber { get; set; }

    public Robot Robot { get; set; }
}
```

"ArmNumber" will represent a unique position for the arm on the robot, basically "Left" vs. "Right". This could be an `int`, `Enum`, `Boolean`, or 'String', in this case I just used an `int` for 0 or 1, left or right. We then have to configure these to act together as a composite PK for the Arm table. With EF Core this currently needs to be done using configuration during OnModelCreating or an EntityTypeConfiguration.

```
public class ArmConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Arm>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Arm> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => new { x.RobotId, x.ArmNumber });
    }
}
```

Now in Robot, we want to correctly associate our new robot arms. If we want a left and right arm reference, we use that ArmNumber combined with the Robot's ID as the FK for each arm. Again, due to the composite nature this means an explicit configuration in EF Core:

```
public class Robot
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Arm LeftArm { get; set; }
    public Arm RightArm { get; set; }
}

public class RobotConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Robot>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Robot> builder)
    {
        builder.HasOne(x => x.LeftArm)
           .WithOne(x => x.Robot)
           .HasForeignKey<Robot>("Id", "LeftArmNumber");
        builder.HasOne(x => x.RightArm)
           .WithOne(x => x.Robot)
           .HasForeignKey<Robot>("Id", "RightArmNumber");
    }
}
```

This would be using 2 shadow properties on Robot for the Left and Right Arm "numbers" (I.e. 0 and 1) so that we can associate each specific arm on the robot to a particular row in the Arms table.  When writing code to create a new robot with two new arms, you will need to ensure that your code initializes each arm's ArmNumber to unique values for left vs. right.